# PHP Toolkit: Query to fetch RecordTypeID along with Custom Object

Tags: apex, query, record-type, php

I've a custom object for which I want the `RecordTypeIDs` returned along with a simple SELECT query.

Example:

```
$q1 = "SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeID FROM Custom_Object__c";
```

Obviously this doesn't return the `RecordTypeID` field. How should I craft my query to get it returned along with in one pass?

Comment: I've no experience of PHP, but from other languages you would use `Custom_Object__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.Id, RecordType.Name FROM Custom_Object__c];` and reference the record type ID via `cos[i].RecordType.Id`.

Comment: Thank you Keith. I tried your approach and the query does fetch RecordType.Id when I run it in Workbench. Funny thing is same query via PHP Toolkit isn't getting me the record type. While it's not throwing any errors, the RecordType.Id variable simply isn't present in the returned resultset.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734033/salesforce-com-retrieve-custom-fields-via-php

Comment: But come to think of it, the query in your question should return the record type ID... are you sure that doesn't work?

Comment: And also "RecordTypeId" is a valid field for any SObject having record type. Use can use this field directly in query to get Record Type Id.

Comment: @AditiJain That's what I thought as well - but the funny thing is it's just not coming through. The value of RecordTypeID or RecordType.Id just refuses to appear in the query. This is totally weird.

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG This is weird. Are you sure that object you are querying does have record types because "RecordTypeId" field exist only on object having record type.

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG And do post your code block (php code block) here, maybe someone else would get a clue.